# SwiftUI vertical ScrollView springs back up and doesn't show all the views within it

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, scrollview

Im working on a project with a similar layout to this where I have a few views stacked within a VStack and a button on the bottom, all embedded in a scrollview.
as you can see in the image the scrollview springs back and doesn't show the button.

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.green)
            .frame(height: 300)
        Spacer()
        ScrollView {
            RectanglesView()
            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                Text("Click me")
            }
            .offset(y: 50)
            .frame(width: 300)
            
        }
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

I do believe that the issue is due to the button's offset since it behaves normally if I remove it, but I don't want to lose the placement of the button.

Comment: It is wrong expectation. `.offset(y: 50)` does not change location/position of view, but only place of drawing.

Comment: apologies :-) I'm not an expert, I'm still learning.

Comment: your content insets are not properly.

Comment: @Priyal how can I fix them? keep in mind that this is just a test code and not how the actual project looks like.

Comment: I have not worked on SWIFTUI... but can try.. Can you share sample project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of offset, add padding, like this and within a VStack (slightly amended code below)

```
    var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(height: 300)
            Spacer()
            ScrollView {
                VStack{
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(height: 300)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.yellow)
                    .frame(height: 300)
                Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                    Text("Click me")
                    }.padding() //instead of offset
                .frame(width: 300)
                }.frame(alignment: .leading)
                
            }
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the Button out of the ScrollView()?

Here is what looks like:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(height: 300)
            Spacer()
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                Rectangle().fill(Color.red).frame(width: 400, height: 200)
                Rectangle().fill(Color.blue).frame(width: 400, height: 200)
                Rectangle().fill(Color.yellow).frame(width: 400, height: 200)
                 Rectangle().fill(Color.green).frame(width: 400, height: 200)
            }
            
            
            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                Text("Click me")
                    .font(.headline)
                           }
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }

}
```